# Need for creating different Projects in Google API console

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I have basically two URL's `http://xyzwebsite.com` (for Development Testing) and `http://abcwebsite.com` (For Production). I have a simple Login mechanism where a user can click on Google Plus icon to log in rather than using their Username and Password. I created one Project for Development with obviously different Client ID and different for Production with a separate client ID.

But I tested both the URL's above with the client ID of Development project and it worked fine. I am wondering why there is a need ot having multiple projects in Google API console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular need. A single project can have several URLs and client IDs for use.

Some reasons you might use multiple projects include:

- Changing project settings in dev without worrying about breaking production
- If you have a development script that gets into an endless loop or something it might use up all of the quota and the production app might start throwing errors
- You might want clear branding on the dev app that explicitly identifies as not production.
- Some unknown reason I can't think of.